# setAttribute not working as it should.

Tags: javascript, html

Have a look at following code

```
function show(id){
if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'none')
  {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = '';
    document.getElementById(id).removeAttribute("disabled");
  }
}

function hide(id){
   document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3jD3W/

When I hide element, i also want to disable it so that value submitted is only for the element that visible now.

However it is not working as expected. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to set the disabled property

```
document.getElementById(id).disabled = true; //false
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById(id).disabled=true;
```

Comment: You had initially written `document.getElementById(id).disabled=false;` ;)

Comment: Not working. I m using firefox. Tried document.getElementById(id).disabled=true;

However, when i print post variables in submited form, it shows value from both dropdowns of name "action".

Comment: no no no..this is for op..not for you ...and yes i did write it by mistake harsha

Comment: @AjayBansal:document.getElementById(id).removeAttribute("disabled");...try this

Comment: @VAGABOND : Mistakes do happen :D

Comment: adding disable attribute is not working. how do i get that? I tried disabled=true; and setAttribute('disabled','disabled');. both do not work. When I submit form, all selects are submitted.

Comment: disabled=true should work....just check using alert if your id reaches inside your code..time for some debugging!!!

Comment: in show/hide functions, elements are getting shown/hidden at run time. so it is reaching that code. that part I have checked :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you calling `hide(id)` anywhere in the jsFiddle, perhaps you didn't post the full code. `Element.setAttribute('disabled', true)` and `Element.disabled = true` both work. Since you're using jQuery, use `prop` instead.

```
$('#desire').change(function() {
    var id = $(this).val(); //returns Share if Share is selected
    var $select = $('#' + id);
    var $actions = $('select[name=action]');
    $actions.hide(); //hide all actions but the selected one
    $select.show().prop('disabled', false); //enable this select
    $('select[name=action]').not($select).prop('disabled', true); //disable all other actions
});

$('input#submit').click(function() {
    $('select[name=action]:hidden').prop('disabled', true); //required in case the form is submitted directly
    alert($('form').serialize()); //only added for testing
    return false; //test
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3jD3W/1/)

Comment: Thanks. That means first answer was also right. +1 to you for pointing out at actual mistake.

Comment: Your question itself is correct. `setAttribute` + `removeAttribute` and using the `disabled` property directly both work. You may have forgotten to disable unselected `select[name=action]`s in your code.